# Gitlab docker instance doesn't take my external URL

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I launched a gitlab container like this:

```
sudo docker run --detach --hostname MY_URL.com --publish 4433:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --name gitlab --og/gitlab --volume /data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

And I have a NGINX configuration like this:

```
server {
  server_name MY_URL.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwardedd_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_URL.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_URL.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
  if ($host = MY_URL.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80;
  server_name MY_URL.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

With this configuration, everything works fine, I can type `https://MY_URL.com` in the address bar of my browser and I can get access to my Gitlab.

The problem is that the link to clone in the repositories is "HTTP" and not "HTTPS". Moreover, it seems that there is a configuration somewhere telling my CI jobs to use `"HTTP://MY_URL.com"` (and it doesn't work because I get an HTTP basic auth error, which I wouldn't get if I used https I think). I read the documentation and I thought I just had to modify the `external_url` parameter:

```
sudo vi /data/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb
```

Adding `external_url 'https://MY_URL.com'`

```
sudo docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

But after doing that I always have a "bad redirection" if I write "http://MY_URL.com" or "https://MY_URL.com". In the nginx logs, I don't have any error but only 301 in the access.log.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are providing an external NGINX configuration that also terminates SSL, you have to apply a configuration to your GitLab instance for [external proxy/load-balancer SSL termination](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#external-proxy-and-load-balancer-ssl-termination).

Normally, when you don't provide `external_url`, the system host name is used and HTTPS is disabled. If you provide an `external_url` with an `https://` scheme, this will activate HTTPS, which is not what you want since you are using an external server (NGINX) for SSL/TLS termination.

```rb
external_url "https://myhost.com"
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

This should be all you need to get GitLab to display the correct hostname in the UI without any other behavior changes.

---

You'll probably also want to [change the proxy headers](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#change-the-default-proxy-headers) since you already have a proxy server in front of GitLab. You'll want to [configure trusted proxies as well as the real-ip header](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#configuring-gitlab-trusted_proxies-and-the-nginx-real_ip-module) to make sure GitLab correctly logs the IP address of your users (instead of the IP of your proxy).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made a drawing to understand your explanations, it's all clear now, I didn't understand the "80" port until your answer. And now I understand more how I can handle my container registry!